# Got banned, but got better since. Can the ban be undone?

Tags: support, post-ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this)

I got banned a day or two ago, because I have asked some questions that were vague/not good enough for the website. I read again and now know how to ask properly.

Now I have 90 rep and one accepted answer with a few with upvotes. And would like to know if there is a way to unlock this ban.

Edit: My question is, what exactly should I do to lift/unlock the ban?

Comment: Answering questions is AFAICT the only way.

Comment: "yet recently got better" -- Asking a duplicate question without carefully reading the ban message or searching for the answer is not a good sign.

Comment: *She turned me into a newt!*

Answer (score 12):

I undeleted two of your questions, which may undo the autoban.  But, please, do the following for me:

1. NEVER PREFACE YOUR TITLE WITH A TAG!  We have tags.  The tag system is pretty damned good.  It is *absolutely pointless to preface your title with the same tag(s) you apply to the question.*  Also, it makes me very *very* angry.  You won't like me when I get angry.  I turn green and my clothes fall off. [Except (thankfully) for my pants.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5846/how-do-the-incredible-hulks-pants-stay-on-but-not-his-shirt)
2. Please edit [both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512880/301-redirect-using-htaccess-file-mod-rewrite-disabled) of these [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374005/vbulletin-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-lib-mysql-mys) to improve the titles and question bodies.  Add more details, make the question titles into succinct descriptions of what you are asking, etc etc.  This will help prevent them from being closed.

In future, think twice before asking a question so that you won't feel the need to delete them.