# Does deleting own answers result in a penalty? (too many or regularly)

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, post-ban, self-delete

[Does deleting my own question or answer attract penalty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74599/does-deleting-my-own-question-or-answer-attracts-penalty) says deleting your own question exceeding some limit results in a penalty.

Is there a penalty for deleting one's own answers? Apparently 5 answers can be deleted per day.

Are there any users that are banned because of deleting answers constantly?

What is the moderators' thoughts about this issue?

For example, if a user gives about ten answers and deletes five of them regularly, will he/she be suspended?

Comment: I don't know about automated penalties, but it certainly automatically raises a flag with text like "possible vandalism multiple deletions:"

Comment: Here on Meta the rules are different.. question doesn't have to be **exact** duplicate in order to get closed, enough it's just related.

Comment: Cheers, I was also "burned" from this pretty early so I'm fine with this by now. :-)

Comment: Can you try to make it more comprehensible?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I was younger when I asked this question :) I hope it makes sense now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no (automatic) penalty but you are limited to 5 deletions per day.

As a rule, only delete answers that don't really add value.

When you make a mistake (and maybe you're getting downvotes), just delete the answer. You can always edit to improve it and then undelete it.

Comment: Got a source for this? Specifics of post bans aren't public, but I'm [pretty sure](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107957/got-banned-but-got-better-since-can-the-ban-be-undone) having lots of deleted questions, even self-deleted, does trigger a question ban. It is probably not too far-fetched to assume that answer bans work like that, too.

Comment: No direct source but deleting answers has been discussed here before and there never was mention of a penalty. Just limits and flags.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell from people posting here and answers I've seen, if you delete too many answers that had negative votes and you don't have enough answers with positive votes you'll eventually get automatic ban saying "We can no longer accept answers from this account", that might get lifted when your existing answers will get upvotes.

I can't tell this for 100% but my advice is: don't delete answers just because you get downvotes on them, unless you have enough "good" answers at your disposal.

Comment: Sorry didn't realize this - as far as I can tell it won't result in any penalty but still - not good practice. Too many of these might get the attention of moderators and result in manual suspension as  awoodland said in a comment to your question.

Comment: Well, posting in SO is not a game.. if you're not sure about your answer, better not post it. :)

Comment: @moguzalp: Related: [Is Stack Overflow a type of game?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48147/is-stack-overflow-a-type-of-game)

Comment: *> if you delete too many answers that had negative votes and you don't have enough answers with positive votes you'll eventually get automatic ban*   `o.O` You get banned for deleting too many *bad* questions and not enough good ones?

Comment: @Synetech yes - see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/) under the section **Are deleted posts taken into account too?** - it says *But if a large percentage of your posts are deleted by yourself or the community, then apparently they were not suitable for the site*

Comment: Ah, I see; your *own* posts. Well that makes sense in general regardless of deletion. If someone is posting lots of questions and answers that are bad, then of course their account will be flagged. However, if someone like that is deleting their own bad questions and answers, then at least it shows a level of self-accountability which is something.

Comment: @Synetech yeah, thought it's obvious, lol.. anyway sometimes I saw cases of users with only one or two existing posts with no downvotes whatsoever that got the ban hammer just because they deleted lots of posts (either questions or answers) together - the system does not see such thing in a good way. Anyway there has been a change so that when you get answers you can't delete your question and I think the same applies for answer with upvotes.